# How to return the most recent value with group by

Tags: mysql

I have this query :

```
SELECT history.trackid, tracklist.artist, tracklist.event, tracklist.data, history.date
FROM history JOIN tracklist ON history.trackid=tracklist.trackid 
GROUP BY trackid 
ORDER BY history.date DESC
```

but I'd like to return the most recent `trackid` (by `date`) when I group on `history`.

Tried with that `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY DESC`, but is not the most recent. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is not sorting by most recent, is because `GROUP BY` creates an aggregate result. You could try:

```
SELECT   h.trackid, t.artist, t.event, t.data
FROM     history AS h
  JOIN   tracklist AS t
    ON   h.trackid = t.trackid 
GROUP BY h.trackid 
ORDER BY MAX(h.date) DESC
```

Because you are already aggregating results, the `MAX(history.date)` should return the maximum (or most recent) date for each group.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` on `history`:

```
SELECT  t.trackid, t.artist, t.event, t.data, h.date
FROM    tracklist t
LEFT JOIN
        history h
ON      h.id =
        (
        SELECT  hi.id
        FROM    history
        WHERE   hi.trackid = t.trackid
        ORDER BY
                hi.trackid DESC, hi.date DESC, hi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `history (trackid, date, id)` for this to work fast.